# compare web-service response values and database query values?

Tags: karate

Can I validate a web-service response with a database query?

Run webservice --> Get response --> Capture **response**
Run corresponding SQL Query
Compare **response** with **SQL query** result

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use Java interop. There are two examples in the [demos](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo). For example, [this one](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/schema/schema.feature).